# What is the difference between "ASP.NET AJAX Server Control" and "ASP.NET Server Control" project types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

What is the difference between "ASP.NET AJAX Server Control" and "ASP.NET Server Control" project types?

Does one project type have advantages over the other?

Are there some things that can be done in one and not the other?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I found this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22384/ASP-NET-AJAX-Controls-and-Extenders

This is a quote from that link and I think it answers my question:

> At first glance, it would seem that the ASP.NET Server Control differs
>   from the other two controls in that it doesn't support AJAX. This
>   isn't completely true, however, and in the first part of this
>   tutorial, I will demonstrate just how far you can go in developing an
>   AJAX-enabled control based on the Server Control alone. While the
>   ASP.NET Server Control does not provide direct access to AJAX scripts,
>   it can implement AJAX scripts encapsulated in other controls such as
>   the UpdatePanel, or the AJAX Extensions Timer Control, to provide AJAX
>   functionality. For control developers who are not all that keen on
>   delving into the intricacies and pitfalls of JavaScript, the Server
>   Control offers an excellent and clean development path.
>
> The AJAX Server Control and the AJAX Server Control Extender differ
>   from the regular ASP.NET Server Control by coupling themselves with
>   JavaScript files, and allowing mapping between properties of a control
>   class and properties of a JavaScript class. When you need
>   functionality not provided by other AJAX Server controls, or simply
>   want to customize your control using client-side script in order to
>   avoid the ASP.NET control life-cycle, then this is the best option.

Edit 2: I just saw that Aghilas Yakoub's answer has the same link :)

Comment: +1 I googled it and didn't find anything relevant http://goo.gl/EJohY

Comment: What are you trying to do..? perhaps you can start there and you won't get such wise remarks..

Comment: How well do you understand AJAX and ASP.Net?

Comment: For those googling freaks.. I just found this on google so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In aspect of projects they are identical. The only one difference is in initial boilerplate code for control created by default. You are absolutely free to add Ajax control to simple server control project as well vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

`ASP.NET AJAX Server Control` bring functionality to an ASP.NET Web page such as :

1 re-rendering parts of a page

2 partial-page update

3 avoiding a full-page postback.

For example you can use Ajax Extender, which is a control that you attach to another ASP.NET control to provide Ajax functionality.

Link very interessant : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22384/ASP-NET-AJAX-Controls-and-Extenders